# ERROR: operator does not exist: mpaa_rating ~~ unknown

Tags: database, postgresql

SELECT rating,title
FROM film
WHERE rating
LIKE 'P_';

got an Error:
ERROR:  operator does not exist: mpaa_rating ~~ unknown
LINE 5: LIKE 'P_';
^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

SQL state: 42883
Character: 46

how to find the R rated movie in the film table with where and like clause

Comment: The message makes it sound like `mpaa_rating` is an `enum` custom type.  What happens if you make it `where mpaa_rating::text like 'P_'` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using the '=' operator rather than LIKE. Your code would be:

```
SELECT title,  
       rating  
FROM  
   film  
WHERE  
  rating = 'R';
```